# magento 2 breadcrumbs swapping in product page

Tags: magento2, product-page, breadcrumbs

Hi here am adding breadcrumbs but in product page its adding swap catagery.

until catagory its working good[image]

in product page its swapping category that should not be added[image]

this is my module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page>
    <body>
    <referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" remove="true" />
    <referenceContainer name="page.top">
        <block class="Harrigo\EverCrumbs\Block\Evercrumbs" 
        name="evercrumbs" as="evercrumbs" template="Harrigo_EverCrumbs::evercrumbs.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

this is my `evercrumbs.phtml` file

```
<?php $crumbs = $block->getCrumbs(); ?>
<?php if ($crumbs && is_array($crumbs)) : ?>
<div class="breadcrumbs">
    <ul class="items">
        <?php foreach ($crumbs as $crumbName => $crumbInfo) : ?>
            <li class="item <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $crumbName ?>">
            <?php if ($crumbInfo['link']) : ?>
                <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $crumbInfo['link'] ?>" title="<?= $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['title']) ?>"><?= $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['label']) ?></a>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?= $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['label']) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

this is layout file `catalog_product_view.xml`

```
public function getCrumbs()
        {
                $evercrumbs = array();

                $evercrumbs[] = array(
                        'label' => 'Home',
                        'title' => 'Go to Home Page',
                        'link' => $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl()
                );

                $path = $this->_catalogData->getBreadcrumbPath();
                $product = $this->registry->registry('current_product');

                $categoryCollection = clone $product->getCategoryCollection();
                $categoryCollection->clear();
                $categoryCollection->addAttributeToSort('level', $categoryCollection::SORT_ORDER_DESC)->addAttributeToFilter('path', array('like' => "1/" . $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getRootCategoryId() . "/%"));
                $categoryCollection->setPageSize(1);
                $breadcrumbCategories = $categoryCollection->getFirstItem()->getParentCategories();
                foreach ($breadcrumbCategories as $category) {
                        $evercrumbs[] = array(
                                'label' => $category->getName(),
                                'title' => $category->getName(),
                                'link' => $category->getUrl()
                        );
                }

                $evercrumbs[] = array(
                                'label' => $product->getName(),
                                'title' => $product->getName(),
                                'link' => ''
                        );

                return $evercrumbs;
        }
```

catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page>
    <body>
    <referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" remove="true" />
    <referenceContainer name="page.top">
        <block class="Harrigo\EverCrumbs\Block\Evercrumbs" 
        name="evercrumbs" as="evercrumbs" template="Harrigo_EverCrumbs::evercrumbs.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

can i get help to solve it ? Thank you in advance

Comment: **No answers??**

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue! Any update from you?